# How can I execute by order at least 5000 http requests from csv using jmeter?

Tags: post, jmeter, httprequest, performance-testing

I am using csv file, with json files names. I want to run many http request, at least 5000, and  around 10,000. each http request will executed once, in the original order (some json depends on the previous).

Now, in the thread group, I configured the number of threads to be the same as my jsons. But from what I read, around 300-400 is the limit of standard computer, otherwise you will get `outOfMemory` exception.

Is there any option that some 100 thread execute the test by order, and still to get them from the csv file (or any other solution)?

I want to execute by order many json http request from csv.

Answer (score 1):

There are several strategies you can take in ramping up your JMeter test to run large numbers of requests.  In most cases including yours, a good approach is to create the test that performs the action that you want, and then take steps to scale it to the volume of requests you need.

The first step is adding the `CSV Data Set Config` element to your test plan.  You can find this when building your test under the “*Config Elements*” menu when adding a new component:

[image: Adding the CSV Data Set Config element to a JMeter test]

This component will allow you to read records from a CSV file and use those values in your test.  There is a good article on how to accomplish that [here](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2021/12/parameterizing-jmeter-tests-from-csv/).

To attain scale of 5000 users, you will need a machine that is capable of handing that volume both in terms of local resources (CPU, memory, *etc*.) as well as network bandwidth capability.  A fast computer with a high-bandwidth internet connection may achieve this, however a cloud-based approach may be more suitable at this level (and higher levels) of concurrency.  This approach will allow you to run multiple simultaneous instances of your test plan at once.  For example, you can run 4 machines generating 1250 requests each to attain your goal of 5000 virtual users (vUsers):

[image: Diagram of how JMeter tests are scaled using a cloud-based architecture]

Depending on the resources required of your test, and the capabilities of the machine, any combination of load generator machines and requests can be used.  You may use 10 machines generating 500 requests each (10 x 500 = 5000 ), or 20 machines generating 250 requests each (20 x 250 = 5000), and so-on. An article overviewing how you can scale a cloud-based JMeter test to any desired concurrency can be found [here](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2021/06/how-many-load-testing-servers/).

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the date of the information as "standard computer" from 2010 differs from the "standard computer" from 2020 so I believe you can kick off much more than 400 users now especially given you follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

If you want to run all requests using data from the CSV file you need to:

1. Add [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and set the number of threads to the desired value

   [image]
2. Add [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) under the Thread Group and make sure that following parameters are set:

   - Recycle on EOF: False
   - Stop thread on EOF: True
   - Sharing Mode: All threads

   [image]
3. Add [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and specify your system under test endpoint there. Also make sure to provide [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)(s) name which you will later define in the CSV Data Set Config

   [image]

This way each thread (virtual user) will pick up next line from the CSV file on each iteration. Your test will end when the last line will be used.

---

For example I have "test.csv" file of 500 lines which looks like:

```
line1
line2
...
line500
```

and here is how JMeter sends data from it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the long anawer. I did sometjing like this, but I need a lot more than 400. Do you know any other way to perform suxh think with less memory used by the computer (because after each user sends his requeat he dont important anymore